# Call to undefined function db2_connect()

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud, netbeans-8, dashdb

I am trying to access to dash db from netbenas 8.0 but it is unable to access throwing the error

> Call to undefined function db2_connect() in
>   /var/www/PhpProject6/demo3.php on line 11 while running through
>   netbeans8.0

```
<?php
$database = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';
$hostname = '';
$port = 50000;

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed.";
}
?>
```

Comment: what should i do help me out

Answer (score 0):

The db2_* functions are in the ibm_db2 extension which you will need to install via pecl so I think first you should check that the extension is installed correctly.  You can do this using phpinfo() which gives information about PHP configuration and installed extensions.

Comment: no there is not ibm_db2 extension so where should i go and enabled db2_connect